# How to get a notification once a MacPort ticket is changed?

Tags: macos, notifications, macports

Recently, I had troubles with a MacPort installation (`port failed to build`).

Searching on `trac.macports.org` I found a ticket number `#xxxxx` which exactly described my problem.

Is it possible to receive a notification (e.g. via email) as soon as a change or solution of the ticket has been reported? If yes how can I establish this notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things

1. Login to trac and goto Preferences and make sure you have your email address in there.
2. Go to the ticket you are interested in. On the second column of information for the ticket. One item is CC: To the right of that there is a button CC me. If you hit this you will get an email anything changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a GitHub account (you can create one for free on their web site) you can login on the Trac page. When you're logged in, you can click the small "Cc me!" button to be advised.

Comment: thx, indeed after login I found a really small `CC me` button